# What is the fastest way to grab a lot of .PNG from external site, convert them to .BMP and store them on own folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

I have a Scheduler (every 10 minutes) set up on my Azure dat fetches around 35 PNGs from an external server, and I want those PNGs (8bit) to be saved on my server, **AND also save them as a 24bit .BMP.**

So what I do now, is loop through a list of URL's, download the .PNGs to my server and then convert those PNGs to a 24bit .BMP.

This is my code:

```
 foreach (string radar in col.Radars)
        {
            if (Counter > 3)
            {
                Uri radarUri = new Uri(radar.RadarImageSource);

                string FileNamePNG = SavePathPNG + (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(radarUri.Query).Get("time") + "x.png").Remove(0, 8);
                string FileNameBMP = SavePathBMP + (HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(radarUri.Query).Get("time") + "x.bmp").Remove(0, 8);
                UpdatedFilePaths.Add(FileNamePNG);
                UpdatedFilePaths.Add(FileNameBMP);

                using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFile(radarUri, FileNamePNG);
                }

                using (Bitmap org = new Bitmap(FileNamePNG))
                {
                    using (Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(org.Width, org.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
                    {
                        bm.SetResolution(org.HorizontalResolution, org.VerticalResolution);
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                        {
                        g.DrawImage(org, 0, 0);
                        g.Dispose();

                        bm.Save(FileNameBMP, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        }
                    }
                }
}
```

**Right now, this job takes quite a while to finish, and the Scheduler's timeout is only 30 seconds.**

Do you guys see any improvements based on my code? Any ideas?

Niels

Comment: StackOverflow is not the place for code review and improvements.

Comment: There are a lot of ways. For example. you could do it in few parallel threads/tasks.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious and easy change would be to make it able to execute in parallel by changing:

```
foreach (string radar in col.Radars)
```

to

```
Parallel.foreach(col.Radars, radar =>
...
);
```